# package-info.java namespace description not working when marshalling

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb, marshalling

I am currently marshalling a java object into a xml file using the WaterML 2.0 api. In the org.w3._1999.xlink package-info I have edited the code to look like below:

`@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchma(namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",elementFormDefault=javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,xmlns={@XmlNs(prefix"xlink",namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink)})`

However, when I marshall my object into the xml file this namespace does not show up.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Show the code where you're doing that

Comment: Marshaller marshal = context.createMarshaller();
  marshal.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "http://www.opengis.net/waterml/2.0 " + "http://schemas.opengis.net/waterml/2.0/waterml2.xsd");
  marshal.marshal(collectionTwo, outputFile);